# Having the day value of date start with 0

Tags: vbscript

I am editing a VBScript so it will take yesterdays date add a string to the front off it and search for that file before moving it to a folder.

```
sDate = day(date)-1

sName= "Blaa" & "_" & sDate
```

Using the above bits of code I would get a result - Blaa_10 or Blaa_9

The issue is the files, I want it to search for when under 10 would be named as Blaa_09.

Is there anyway I can format the value day so when it is under 10 it starts with 0? Think I could write an If statement to do this but was hoping there is another way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canonical way to left-pad a day of month with a zero in VBScript looks like this:

```
Right("0" & Day(Date), 2)
```

Comment: Cheers Ansgar, use padding every day and it never dawned on me to use padding. Always a simplier way.

Answer (score 0):

Just went with

```
sDay = day(date) -1

IF sDay < 10 Then
        sDate = "0"& sDay & monthname(month(DateAdd("m",-1,Date)), True) & year(date)
        WScript.Echo "Date = " & sDate
```

This worked fine, if anyone has an easier way please feel free to share.